# If Category A data is not available the show category B In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
category    item    Price   status
       A    Mobile1 1300    2
       A    Mobile1 1300    3
       A    Mobile1 1300    2
       B    Mobile1 1200    2
       B    Mobile1 1200    2
       A    Mobile2 2000    2
       A    Mobile2 2000    2
       B    Mobile2 1800    2
       B    Mobile2 1800    2
       C    Mobile2 1300    2
       A    Mobile3 3000    3
       B    Mobile3 2500    2
       C    Mobile3 2000    2
       A    Mobile3 3000    3
```

This is my data I want Show result like:

```
category    Item    Price   Status  quantity
       A    Mobile1 1300    2       2
       A    Mobile2 2000    2       2
       B    Mobile3 2500    2       1
```

I tried below Query:

```
select  category, Item, Price, Status, count(Category) quantity from table1
where status = 2 and category = case category when 'A' then 'A' else 'B' End
group by category, Item, Price,Status
```

I tried to show all data of category A and if category A Item data is not available then show category B Items

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` with `not in` like this:

```
select category, Item, Price, status, count(Category) quantity
from table1
where status = 2
    and category = 'A'
group by category, Item, Price, status

union all

select category, Item, Price, status, count(Category) quantity
from table1
where status = 2
    and category = 'B'
    and item not in (
        select item
        from table1
        where status = 2
            and category = 'A'
        )
group by category, Item, Price, status
```

Comment: when i run second query after union All. The result is blank.

Comment: when i Replace Not exists to Not in then its working. like item not in (select Item from table1 where status = 2 and category = 'A'). thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to prioritize the categories for each item.  You can use `dense_rank()` for the priorities and then aggregation to get the summaries just for the category you want:

```
select min(category) as category, item, avg(price) as price,
       max(status) as status, count(*)
from (select t1.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by item
                                (case when category = 'A' then 1
                                      when category = 'B' then 2
                                      when category = 'C' then 3
                                      else 4
                                 end)
                                ) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
      where status = 2
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1
group by item;
```